# Transmitir informações entre páginas html com jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

Boa tarde pessoa, tudo bem?

Em meu projeto, possuo uma lista de imóveis, todos diferentes entre si. Ao clicar em algum deles, deve-se abrir uma página de detalhes com informações únicas a respeito do imóvel clicado. O problema é comunicar a minha página de resultados com a página de detalhes.

Tinha em mente fazer a comunicação através de um id... Vejam meu exemplo:

```
<!-- RESULTADO.html -->
    <ul id="resultado-pesquisa">
        <li class="itens-pesquisa"><a id="0101" >Clicar para detalhes</a></li>
        <li class="itens-pesquisa"><a id="0202" >Clicar para detalhes</a></li>
        <li class="itens-pesquisa"><a id="0303" >Clicar para detalhes</a></li>
    </ul>
```

O que eu preciso é: Clicar na ancora e passar a `id` para a página de detalhes via jQuery! É possível?

Obrigado, boa semana a todos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Joao Souza pode fazer com [hash](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp), assim escusa de operar com cookies para isso:

```
<ul id="resultado-pesquisa">
    <li class="itens-pesquisa"><a id="0101" href="detalhes.html#0101">Clicar para detalhes</a></li>
    <li class="itens-pesquisa"><a id="0202" href="detalhes.html#0202">Clicar para detalhes</a></li>
    <li class="itens-pesquisa"><a id="0303" href="detalhes.html#0303">Clicar para detalhes</a></li>
</ul>
```

Depois na página `detalhes.html`, consegue obter o id na href onde clicou na página anterior, por exemplo na pág `detalhes.html#0101`:

```
var id_imovel = location.hash;
console.log(id_imovel); // #0101
```